# STM32 Repetition Counter

Tags: embedded, stm32, counter

what is the max value of the Repetition Counter register?
Because i am trying to use a TIM1 as PWM output.
Period = 50kHz
Clock = 72Mhz
72Mhz/50kHz = 1440Hz  -> PWM freq

So if I set Repetition Counter to 1440 is should generate an interrput one every sec. But it doesnt work that way?

Could you explain me why?
Greets

Comment: This [question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/177890/38335) (and answer) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The repetition counter register documentation tells us that it only uses the lower 8 bits, so the maximum value is 255.

To do what you want to do (generate an interrupt every 1 second), you should use a capture-compare register which are 16 bits.

I haven't used the repetition counter yet, but from what I can gather in a short reading, it's probably there for some motor control stuff where you want to change the PWM frequency after a certain number of periods of the current PWM frequency.

Also try to improve on your units handling. Periods are commonly measured in seconds and a frequency divided by another frequency gives a result without a unit. (Units can be very helpful to check if you have calculated the right things)

Comment: Thanks a lot, i have searched through documentation, but couldnt find it. And yeah, little slip-up with units.

Comment: @KarolŻurowski the register description is at the end of each chapter for the peripheral. While all the documentation text is very helpful, the bare-metal register view is sometimes best to answer questions like this.